# CSS for module size (similar to @media)?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla Module that I'm trying to keep responsive for different screen sizes but displaying and hiding columns.   This works well on full page displays.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .team_name { display:none; }
    .team_abbr { display:inline-block;}
    .overall { display: inline-block;}
    .divisional { display:inline-block;}
    .wide { display:none;}
    #btn_row { display:inline-block;}
    #div_split { display:none;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .team_name { display: inline-block; }
    .team_abbr { display:none;}
    .overall { display: inline-block;}
    .divisional { display:inline-block;}
    .wide { display:inline-block;}
    #btn_row { display:none;}
    #div_split ( display:inline-block;)
}
```

But now my challenge is that I want to have this same page/module used inside another page as a module position (which is only about 200 pixels wide).

Is there a CSS command similar to @media that will get the module width instead of the entire page width that the module is on?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a class to your module, then size the elements inside the module relative to their parent (ie the module)

(1) Start by going to the module you want to work on > advanced tab > module class suffix

(2) Add a class and remember to include a space at the start, eg ' my-module-class'

(3) Finally, size your module elements relative to the module, eg

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {

    .team_abbr { 
       ...
       width:50%;
     }  
}
```

Good luck, I hope this helps!